# Concatenate & Indirect Functions

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out how to concatenate Multiple indirect lookups into a single formula.

eg:

```
Values               refs

A          B         C
1
2 Yes                A2                  
3 No                 A3
4 Yes                A4
```

I would like to INDIRECT C2,C3,C4 all together (Concatenate) to get the value "YesNoYes"
The reason i need to do this is because in reality the reference numbers in column C are all over the place.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft have not yet produced a concatenating worksheet function with the ability to process arrays, so unless the number of strings to be concatenated is never much more than that given in your example, i.e. 3, then a formula-based solution will be unfeasible and you will need to look at implementing some VBA. If, however, you are certain that the maximum number of strings to be concatenated will never be more than, say 5, then I could provide you with a formula-based solution.

Comment: Sadly it will be much more than 3. Any recommendations around what i should code VBA wise? im not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfortunately no expert in VBA, but:

```
Sub ConcatYN()

Dim Indrcts As Range, YesNos As Range

Set Indrcts = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set YesNos = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each c In YesNos
    x = x & Range(c)
    Range("E1").Value = x
Next c

End Sub
```

Where **Range("E1")** indicates that cell E1 will contain the concatenated output, and your values and indirect references are assumed to be in columns A and C respectively, both beginning in row 2 (**Range("A2:A"...** and **Range("C2:C"...** etc. in the code), with no other data in these two columns after these ranges terminate.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you agree to use other column to build, you can use:

```
D2 -> =INDIRECT(C2)
D3 -> =CONCATENATE(D2;INDIRECT(C3))     ' and autocomplete...
```

And take the last built using something like:

```
=INDEX(D2:D18;COUNTA(D2:D18))
```

and hide the column "D".